# Memory leak if no call to stopservice()?

Tags: android

I've been trying to find an answer to this question, but cannot find anything. Say that I start a `Service` in `Android`, bind it to an `Activity`, but fail to ever call `stopService()`. Does this create a memory leak? The code that I am reviewing does call `unbindService()`, for what that might be worth, but never `stopService()`.

The code is kind of irrelevant since it is mostly boiler plate, but I'll post it here as a formality:

```
@Override
public void startMyService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

This is a service that plays audio feeds. There are calls to stop the audio and unbind the service, but nowhere does it call stopService(intent). I'm obviously going to add that call, but it just made me curious about whether this situation was creating a memory leak.

Thanks for any advice or references where this question may have already been answered.

Comment: If your bind method gives your service hard reference to the activity and you don't clear it on `onUnbind`, then you're leaking activity. Otherwise the service lingers doing nothing.

Comment: Can you post your service class. And why you don't use foreground service is better for audio playback. See this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services